# Linq group by with multiple keys

Tags: c#, linq

If I have an IEnumerable, how can I split them using linq to give a list within a list of executions that are unique based on `Tenant`, `UserId`, `AccountId` and `Bucket`.

I am looking to get a list of lists of the form `IEnumerable<(Tenant,UserId,AccountId,Bucket),IEnumerable<TradeExecuted>>`.

```
public class TradeExecuted : INotification
{
    public Guid Tenant { get; init; }
    public UserId UserId { get; init; }
    public string AccountId { get; init; }
    public string Bucket { get; init; }
    /* other fields */
}
```

I have given the UserId object below, but believe concerns with uniqueness are addressed via the `ValueObject` [per this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects).

```
public class AccountId : ValueObject
{
    public string Account { get; init; }
    public string Broker { get; init; }

    public AccountId(string broker, string account)
    {
        Broker = broker;
        Account = account;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Broker;
        yield return Account;
    }
}
```

A dictionary is OK but having a mind freeze with the below:

```
var splitMessages = messages
        .GroupBy(x => (x.Bucket, x.AccountId, x.Tenant, x.UserId))
        .ToDictionary(key => key.Key);
```

If easier to get a list of lists, am ok with that also - pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need to do anything beyond the grouping, `GroupBy` provides a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TElement>>` which `IGrouping` is an [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=net-6.0) of `IEnumerable<out TElement>` So as you can see just using `GroupBy()` provides you with a list of lists.

That is why I could do this.

---

```
var splitMessages = messages
    .GroupBy(x => (x.Bucket, x.AccountId, x.Tenant, x.UserId));
var castedMessages = (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TradeExecuted>>)splitMessages;
```

---

I can not say I understand exactly what this form is `IEnumerable<(Tenant,UserId,AccountId,Bucket),IEnumerable<TradeExecuted>>` [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-6.0) is described as having one covariant generic argument. It looks like what you want is exactly what IEnumerable<IGrouping<..>> offers which is a list of lists which has the key

---

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var splitMessages = messages
        .GroupBy(x => (x.Bucket, x.AccountId, x.Tenant, x.UserId))
        .ToDictionary(key => key.Key, values = values.Select(s => s);
```